# PyGI Edit Image Color

Tags: python, user-interface, colors, pygtk

Can any tell me how to change image color using PyGI (or PyGTK)? 
I need method or property, like "ImageColour" in CEGUI, what changing non-alpha channels of image. For example:
I have one picture, its just white round. I need to use this round in a different places of interface, with different colors. And I won't to create another dublicates of this round, bcs, for example, I need 256 different colors.
And Pictures Example:

[This is picture with white round, what I've got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axnBz.png)

[This is picture with round, what color I want to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGt0q.png)

Here is functions, what I'm using to change color:

```
image = gtk.Image()
image.set_from_file("images/button.png")
pix_buffer = image.get_pixbuf()
pix_buffer.fill(0xA32432FF)
image.set_from_pixbuf(pix_buffer)
```

Thats doesn't work correctly. Thats fill full image to quad of red color.

Another idea is *modify_fg*/*modify_base*, but here works only *modify_bg* what changing only background (and doesn't changing white color)

Answer (score 0):

I've been playing with this for the last days, and it is not entirely easy to treat `pixbuf` as a immediate representation of the pixels. One of the reasons is that the `GdkPixbuf` software determines a 'rowstride' which causes 'jumps' in the addressing of the image.

Until I can investigate more, the simplest solution I've found is to convert the pixbuf to a `PIL.Image`, do the operations there, and convert back to pixbuf. These are the two function that do the conversion:

```
def pixbuf2image(self, pxb):
    """ Convert GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf to PIL image """
    data = pxb.get_pixels()
    w = pxb.get_width()
    h = pxb.get_height()
    stride = pxb.get_rowstride()
    mode = "RGB"
    if pxb.get_has_alpha():
        mode = "RGBA"
    img = Image.frombytes(mode, (w, h), data, "raw", mode, stride)
    return img

def image2pixbuf(self, img):
    """ Convert PIL or Pillow image to GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf """
    data = img.tobytes()
    w, h = img.size
    data = GLib.Bytes.new(data)
    pxb = GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new_from_bytes(data, GdkPixbuf.Colorspace.RGB,
            False, 8, w, h, w * 3)
    return pxb
```

Luckily, `new_from_bytes` takes into account the rowstride automatically, and saves the continuous bytes in `data` in the correct manner in memory.

In `PIL` (`Pillow` for Python3) you can do many operations on the image, including pixel-by-pixel access. Do note that `pixbuf` is always using `RGB(A)` components, so you have to be careful with the conversions and operations!

In any case, the latter function shows how to convert a memory (`bytes`) array to a `GdkPixbuf`, if you want to construct the image directly.